# is there any way to pass string contains '+' via the Querystring

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I need to pass `'+'` via the  `QueryString`.

some special character can be passed  by using  'Encode' .. but '+'

I know the one solution,  If I replace '+' with other character.

But it's not the perfect solution.

[edited]

well I used `escape()` javascript function to encode.

escape function can't encode `+`   .   is the another function to encode  on javascript?

Comment: I GIVE UP TO PASS UNICODE querystring correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than handling on a case by case basis, with Javascript you can encode all data you pass via query string with [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)

```
<script>
var data = ")(@&^$@*&^#!(!*++="; 
var encodedData = encodeURIComponent(data); 
alert(encodedData);
</script>
```

Comment: it's very nice.  well. how can I decode the encoded string?. I tried to decode using `Server.UrlDecode` .  But It can't decode perfectly in UNICODE.

Comment: The data will already be decoded for you when you access it through the QueryString collection.

Answer (score 3):

Use `%2b` to pass the `+` character.

Answer (score 1):

The space character is usually passed as `%20`.
The same way, the plus sign can be passed as `%2B`

Answer (score 0):

In ASCII, the hex code for `+` is `2B`, so you should be able to just use `%2B` instead of `+`.

http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+java